# dictionary of built in methods in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, built-in

I'm trying to create a dictionary of built in methods but I'm getting the output as shown in below. Why is this happening? I just want to understand that.

```
>>>
>>> dict = {'a': print('avc'), 'b': print('bbbb'), 'c': print('aaa')}
avc
bbbb
aaa
>>> dict
>>> {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None}
>>>
```

Also, if someone is trying to understand where I'm coming from then they can have a look at this question:
[Link to the question I was trying to solve when  I thought the above would be useful.](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-lists)

Comment: Why a *screenshot?!*

Comment: And what does the title have to do with the question?

Comment: @jonrsharpe so that people can understand what I did and what output I got.

Comment: So copy and paste **the text** into the question.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm trying to include the built-in functions in the dictionary and hence the title? Does that sound wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you call the function `print` while the dictionary is created. You're storing the result of the **calls** in the dictionary , not the **function** `print`. As a result, your dictionary is going to be populated by `None` values representing the *return value* of the `print` calls.

What you should do is have a structure like:

```
d = {'abc': print}
```

And now your dictionary will store the actual function `{'abc', <function print>}`

You can then call these functions by iterating through the values of the dictionary:

```
for str, func in d.items():
    func(str)

# prints abc
```

---

Additionally, you need to avoid using names like `dict` for your variables. They ***mask*** the [built-in types](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html) for python (in your case the [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict) built-in type).

Generally opt for other names, like `d`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now, I understand that I was storing the function calls which caused the NONE value to be stored in corresponding key. I tried other functions which return a value and it stored those value, so my query has been answered.

Comment: Exactly, you've got it perfectly! :-) Just remember next time you try and ask a question on here it is good to include the code *in* the question itself (so you don't get downvoted and all). I have edited your question and added the code for now but just remember that. Good day, Gourav.

Comment: I didn't know that dict was a keyword; I always try to use meaningful names and avoid any name conflicts or masking in this case.

Comment: Thanks and I'll remember the tip about screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

`print` is a function that prints stuff to the screen, and returns None

When you do an assignment, you are saying " the hash value a equals what print("avc") returns"

This means `print("avc")` is invoked (which is why you see the value printed) and it returns None, so the value of a is None in your dict.

Answer (score 0):

Print doesn't return a value.

Imagine it's definition like this

```
(void) print(object):
   do magic io stuff to make object appear in the console
```

Therefore, when you are assigning print('avc') for key 'a' in the dictionary, it gets a none.